# How can I redirect a subdirectory to a directory and query string?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to redirect URLs on my site.

I'd like to have it so that `/questions/12345` and `/users/12345` redirect to `/questions/display.php?id=12345` and `/users/display.php?id=12345`, respectively.

I'd *also* like to add a shortcut, sort of like Stack Exchange, whereby `/q/12345/6789` is rewritten to `/questions/display.php?id=12345&refer=6789`.

So far, having looked through [several](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489) [sources](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/subdirectories-redirect-query-string/), I've got this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+) /users/display.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+) /questions/display.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /questions/display.php?id=$1&referer=$2 [NC]
```

However, when I navigate to `/questions/12345`, I get a 500 Internal Server Error - so clearly, this isn't working.

On looking at the Apache error log, it reveals this is what's going on:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

What's going wrong here, and what *should* I have done?

Comment: Wouldn't the regex `[^/]+` also match the text `display.php?id=` ?  Perhaps you should adjust your regex to match only the pattern you're interested in, i.e. something more like `^users/([0-9]+)`.  Also, when you get the 500 error, what is added to your Apache logs?  A 500 is just what gets passws back to the browser; your log should contain the reason for the 500.

Comment: Right, so you're rewriting `/users/123/` to `/users/display.php?id=123`, which then gets rewritten to `/users/display.php?id=display.php?id=123`, etc.

Comment: @ghoti - The error is in the post. However, your 0-9 idea appears to have fixed it... somehow. Chuck that in an answer.

Comment: I'll make it an answer for you to accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect is catching itself.  :-)

Note the regex atom `([^/]+)`.  This means "any run of one or more characters which are not a forward slash".  The text `display.php?id=` matches, so on your first request for

```
/users/123
```

you are rewritten to

```
/users/display.php?id=123
```

But the redirect doesn't stop there.  The new URL also passes through the rewrite engine, to be written to:

```
/users/display.php?id=display.php?id=123
```

And your rewritten URL keeps getting rewritten until you hit a limit, as noted in your log.

To solve this, you can make your initial regex more restrictive.

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+) /users/display.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

You can also tell the rewrite engine that a particular rule is the "Last" rule, so it won't reprocess the line (or run it through any other rules):

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+) /users/display.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Finally, you can add extra protection by telling Apache not to apply rewrite rules if the requested path is to a file:

```
# Exempt requests to directories...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Exempt requests directly to files...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite /users/###
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+) /users/display.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is a bit of a belt-and-suspenders-and-moresuspenders solution, but the idea that you want to apply protection in any and every way possible is a sound one.

Comment: Note that the `?id=123` would get lost when the rewrite engine loops

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the rewrite engine loops so what you rewrite to ends up matching the same rule again. You can try adding some conditions to prevent this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+) /users/display.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+) /questions/display.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /questions/display.php?id=$1&referer=$2 [NC,L]
```